# Search with managed property in Blog

Tags: search-results, managed-property

I have a brand new Blog template site and created some test Posts as fellow,

[image]

As you can see, there a 3 posts contain the "Category" of "Events".

When I search with "PostCategory:Events" and the result is as follow,
[image]

I have already run a Full Crawl before I perform the search.

Anyone have any idea why it only shows 2 results instead of 3?

Comment: Could be the fact that the search engine by default trims duplicate results from a search ( your documents seems like example documents with very similar names and content)

Comment: @RobertLindgren you are right, that seem to be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be the fact that the search engine by default trims duplicate results from a search ( your documents seems like example documents with very similar names and content)